# Downgrading the SQL version in webDeveloper

Tags: sql-server, visual-web-developer-2010

i have a problem that when i am trying to enter the `sql` `database` of my web on a computer at my school- it doesnt let me and says that the version of the sql is higher then the one that is installed on that computer.

Since i am not allowed to install or re install anything on the computer at my school i have to downgrade my sql at home.
EDIT:
i may will be able to upgrade the school sql, but not sure. so if u can write both how to upgrade and how to downgrade

How can i do that?
`webDevelor 2010` on both computers.
 my sql version is 661, and the school's server supports only  655 and earlier versions

Tnx for the Help :D

Comment: R u using xampp server at home?

Answer (score 0):

Download SQL Server 2008 Express and try opening your sql database in this.It would be helpful if you can exactly mention which sql version you are running and which version your school is running.I don't think there is a way to just downgrade the sql alone in web developer 2010 the only way around would be to download a more older edition of web developer which has a lower version of sql by default.

Comment: i could check on sunday, ill write it here then

Comment: allright, my sql version is 661, and the school's server supports only  655 and earlier verios